# Unable to insert null values in SQL Table using SQL bulk

Tags: sql-server, excel, sqlbulkcopy

I am trying to upload Excel file data into SQL table,

below is my code

```
using (SqlConnection objCon = new SqlConnection(strCoon))
                {
                    objCon.Open();
                    SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("DeleteDump", objCon);
                    sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 0;
                    sqlCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;                      
                    sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();       
                    using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy sqlBulk = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy(strCoon))
                    {
                        sqlBulk.BulkCopyTimeout = 0;
                        sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = "InformationDump";

                        for (int i = 0; i < DumpResources.GetLength(0); i++)
                        {
                            sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add(dt.Columns[i].ColumnName.ToString(), DumpResources[i, 1].ToString());
                        }
                        sqlBulk.WriteToServer(dt);// Getting error at this line
                    }
                }
```

I am getting error as `The given value of type String from the data source cannot be converted to type datetime of the specified target column.`
Excel sheet I am trying to upload contains null data which I am unable to upload in destination table.

Comment: Change the display format of that column in Excel to dtaetime format

Comment: @sepupic .. I already did that, but it is not helping me.

Comment: In this case change the data type of the problem target column. Make it varchar(...) for now, load the data, change the column to be datetime again

Comment: first check if the column in your destination table in the database accepts nulls...if not, modify the column to accept a default, in this case if it is a varchar column, just pass an empty string....also you can try to explicitly convert the datatable column to datetime or the destination's table column type before passing to "sqlBulk.WriteToServer(dt)"

Answer (score 0):

I guess the issue is that you are trying to convert a null value to a string and then try to put it in a field that only accepts datetime.
Check if there is anything (so notnull) before converting it to string.